# Windows 10 Bluetooth all of sudden sees my headphones as an unknown device

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, bluetooth

Today I unpaired my bluetooth headphones from my laptop for something and after I tried to pair it again, it keeps listing them as an unknown device, and multiple unknown devices show up. I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling bluetooth drivers, restarting bluetooth services, and I'm not sure what other steps I should take to fix this issue, especially since they were working perfectly fine for years and before I unpaired them.

[unknown devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTLw6.png)

Comment: How to add an inline image.  Copy and paste in the body. Windows has an inbuilt hotkey (Win + Shift + S) which executes Snipping Tool. Any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2):

I would start with the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Go to Settings->Devices->Bluetooth and Other devices menu and remove your headphones from your computer.

   2. This may be enough to fix your problem, if nothing appears in device manager skip to step 6.
2. Press **WIN+X** key and select device manager
3. Goto Bluetooth Devices and right click the Bluetooth headphones device name if it appears, and select Uninstall Devic

   1. If it asks to uninstall the driver from you computer, select that too although that's unlikely since it's probably a built-in driver
      [image: Device Manager]
4. Go down to Sound, Video, and Game Controllers and select the Corresponding audio devices and uninstall them too if they appear.
5. Restart your computer
6. If your headphones remember connected devices, read it's manual to figure out how to clear all paired devices.
7. You should know be starting "Fresh". Go ahead and try to re-pair your headphones. If it still appears as Unknown, wait a bit to see if will eventually load in. Bluetooth can be a bit finicky sometimes.

If your still having problems, I would try to update your Bluetooth drivers or see if a recent update broke it.