# No sound for Bluetooth device on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I recently got a new pair of Soundcore Liberty 3 Pro.
While listening for the first time to music on my work notebook, I did hear some cracks in the audio and tried to fiddle with the bluetooth driver settings in the hope to fix these issues. But somehow I managed to completly break the headphones.

Now the device will be recognized and pair just fine, but I'm not able to hear any sound. They still do work on every other device. What I tried so far:

1. Rebooting the notebook.
2. Resetting the headphones (removing all paired devices)
3. Deinstalled every occurence of the device in the device manager.
4. Searching for drivers for the specific device (couldn't find any).
5. Trying different bluetooth drivers from the pre-installed drivers list.
6. Windows 10 Troubleshooting for Audio / Bluetooth.

If there was a way to reset all bluetooth devices (like if I would have a fresh install of Windows), I would want to try that out. Is there a way to do this (maybe through a PS script or manually by editing the registry)?

Edit:

Other Bluetooth headphones are still working.

On the Windows 10 Bluetooth & Other Devices page, my headphones are list as "Other Devices", whereas my other headphones are listed as "Audio":

[image]

Comment: Hi @Eddi - Two questions. First, have you tried the pairing the headphones with a different device (e.g. a phone) and did they work on the other device?  This test (if the headphones are  unproblematic on the other device) would allow you to discount the possibility that there is a physical setting on the headphones themselves, rather than on the Windows machine, which is causing the problem.  Second, have you tried physically connecting to the Windows machine with a headphone jack rather than Bluetooth?  Again, this test is designed to narrow down the problem.  Let us know the results.

Comment: Hi @TechnoCat , yes I did both of these. My headphones will connect to my other notebook and my phone without any problems. The headphone jack is working and even other bluetooth headphones are working.

Comment: Just to confirm I'm not missing anything, you're saying that the Soundcore Liberty 3 Pro headphones will play sound correctly when they are connected to your Windows 10 work laptop via the headphone jack?  But the sound stops when you unplug the headphone jack and pair the same headphones to the same laptop via Bluetooth?

Comment: No, they are bluetooth headphones, so they can't be connected to the headphone jack. I meant other headphones do still work with the headphone jack.

Comment: However, I managed to solve this issue. I followed what was described in the answer to the post here rigorously: https://superuser.com/questions/1547114/windows-10-bluetooth-all-of-sudden-sees-my-headphones-as-an-unknown-device 
I already tried everything laid out in the answer seperately. The key was to follow everything step by step.

Comment: Great to hear that you solved it!  I've had similar problems with a couple of Bluetooth audio devices on my Windows in the past, so I was trying to whittle down the likely causes before proposing answers.  Happy listening!